# FormGroup thinks it's required when no validators are specified

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form with a nested FormGroup:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  kitType: [
    '', [
      Validators.required,
    ]
  ],
  diagnosisCode: [
    '', [
      Validators.required,
    ]
  ],
  delayKitShipmentDate: new FormGroup({
    year: new FormControl(''),
    month: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
    day: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
  })
});
```

The `delayKitShipmentDate` is optional, and does not have any validators specified on the controls, yet my form is reporting `invalid` unless I specify values for the year, month and day controls.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: I'm on Angular 2.4.1. I think in my case, the FormGroup might not be valid because it's untouched.

Comment: I need to do some custom validation on that nested form group as well, so I may need to manually trigger that. If all else fails, I'll upgrade to 2.4.4 and see if I get the same result as you.

Comment: can you post your template code?

Comment: I actually tried your exact implementation and got the same result. I ended up punting and wrote a custom getter to check for the fields I wanted and based the submit button's `[disabled]` on that.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested with the following code/template:

```
testForm:FormGroup;
constructor(public fb:FormBuilder) {
this.testForm = this.fb.group({
          kitType: [
            '', [
              Validators.required,
            ]
          ],
          diagnosisCode: [
            '', [
              Validators.required,
            ]
          ],
          delayKitShipmentDate: new FormGroup({
            year: new FormControl(''),
            month: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
            day: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
          })
        });
}
```

template

```
<div  [formGroup]="testForm">
            kitType<input formControlName="kitType"  id="kitType"/>
            diagnosisCode<input formControlName="diagnosisCode"  id="diagnosisCode"/>
            <div formGroupName="delayKitShipmentDate">
              year<input  formControlName="year"  id="year"/>
              month<input  formControlName="month"  id="month"/>
              day<input  formControlName="day"  id="day"/>

            </div>
            <div>
              <p>Form: {{ testForm.value | json }}</p>
              <p>Form status: {{ testForm.status }}</p>
            </div>

          </div>
```

your code should work
[image: testForm]

@angular version:^2.4.4

Comment: Well, even after upgrading to Angular 2.4.4, I'm still not seeing the same result you are. I still have to select a date. Grr.